How to read parquet files that contain the same data, but where a couple of them have different data types on Spark
I have multiple parquet files, that have the same number of columns, but some of them have inconsistencies on datatypes.
For example, one of the files file1.parquet has a column called Cost with datatype int, and another file2.parquet has the same column Cost, but with datatype int64.
When I try to read the files using :
df = spark.read.parquet("s3://mybucket/costs")

I get the following error:

    Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o95.showString.
    : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 5.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.3 in stage 5.0 (TID 17) (172.35.121.254 executor 3): org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionException: Parquet column cannot be converted in file file1.parquet/part-00015-ae4e57f0-49ad-4ac2-85b5-86ee31c55382-c000.snappy.parquet. Column: [cost], Expected: int, Found: INT64


I know I can re-write the data with a explicit schema, but that means traverse all the files.
Is there a better approach to suggest a schema that spark can use to perform the datatype conversion if the field does not conform to the schema?
I saw there are some options to discard records with FAILFAST or DROPMALFORMED modes, but I want is to see if I can tell spark to perform a cast automatically for me when I try to perform the read so I don't miss any data
I tried as well mergeSchema
spark.read.option("mergeSchema", "true").parquet("s3://my_bucket/my_data")

And got the following error:
 Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to merge fields 'order_cost' and 'order_cost'. Failed to merge incompatible data types int and bigint

I tried re-writing the data as follows without success as well:
spark.read.parquet("s3://mybucket/mydata").withColumn("cost", col("order_cost").cast(LongType())).write.mode("overwrite").option("overwriteSchema", "true").parquet("s3://mybucket/mydata")

Error:
Parquet column cannot be converted in file s3://mybucket/mydata.parquet/part-00015-ae4e57f0-49ad-4ac2-85b5-86ee31c55382-c000.snappy.parquet. Column: [cost], Expected: int, Found: INT64

please add code which you tried so far

added more detail on the options tried when using read parquet

Tried several more approaches and included on the description. No luck yet

Your only solution is to rewrite each individual file per https://stackoverflow.com/a/53618226/1028537
mergeSchema cannot know to handle each differing file, it's purpose is to evolve schemas when adding columns - not to guess how to interpret incompatible column types
